# Why wont divs sit inline

Tags: html, css

I read up on inline positioning:

http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

And then I created a test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<style type="text/css">
    p {display:inline}

    .inline
    {
        display:inline;
    }
</style>


<div style="display:inline;">

    <p>Hello</p>

    <p>Pete</p>

</div>

<div class="inline">

    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Pete</div>

</div>

 <div class="inline">

    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Pete</p>

</div>



</form>
```

However when I view the page I the middle two divs are not inline, they are one after the other.

What I dont undestand is why the second two elements arent displayed inline? I mean they shouldn't be according to the article. Paragraph and Divs are both block level so why are only the paragraph elements going 'inline'?

Any help much appreciated.

Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divs in the second div do not have the class `inline` and hence are not inline elements. If you change your CSS definition to this:

```
div, p {display:inline}
```

Then everything will sit nicely on one line.

Comment: Ok, but I thought the two divs below should inherit the styling of the enclosing div? Thats how css works isnt it? So those two inner divs should get display:inline set to them shouldnt they?

Comment: @user223863, you need to explicitly set the `display` attribute to `inherit` in order for the inner divs to inherit the property. If inheritance would be automatic, then all of your elements would have the same properties as your `body` element, for example. And what would happen then if you had set `width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;` to the `body` element? You'd probably not want those properties applied also on the descendants.

Comment: Hi, okay well yeah things do inherit from the body dont they? If I set a font in the body then i dont expect to have to then set the font in each div they just inherit?

Answer (score 3):

You are defying the very purpose of divs. If you want to use inline elements, a better options would be to go for `<span>` elements.

If you want you divs to appear side-by-side, you shoud use `float`. for example `float:left` each div.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` tags by their nature are block level elements. Unless you specifically say so in your CSS rules, they will remain so.

You have two options here.

Write a CSS rule that matches each div inside a bounding div with a class of inline.
e.g.

```
.inline div {display:inline}
```

But I'd advise against this.

Best option is to apply the class inline, as you have already written to each div you want to display inline. e.g.

```
.inline {display:inline}
```

The bonus of this method is that you can apply this class to any element, rather than having to specify a new rule for each html element you want displayed inline.

As an aside - you should perhaps try using floats instead of displaying your divs inline. You may run into display and position issue going forward, depending how much information goes into your inline styled divs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the class on the inner divs:

```
<div class="inline">Hello</div>
<div class="inline">Pete</div>
```